# Рендер JS вьюхи для AJAX Rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails

У меня есть *show.html.haml* вьюха, которая показывает количество лайков на посте

```
= @post.likes.count
```

В контроллере в экшене *create* прописал:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render template: 'posts/show.js.haml' }
  format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
end
```

При рендере html, редиректит на этот же пост, т.е. просто обновляется страница для отображения нового лайка.
Как мне сделать отправку через JS, чтобы не нужно было обновлять всю страницу?

Я создал show.js.haml для рендера формата js, но что туда писать?

Для баттона *Like* добавил remote: true, чтобы вызывался ajax:

```
= link_to 'Like', post_likes_path(@post), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-outline-dark', remote: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я переместил строчку

```
= @post.likes.count
```

в новый паршиал *_likescount.html.haml*.

В *show.js.erb* добавил код для рендера этого паршиала на своей вьюхе:

```
var likes = document.querySelector("#likes");
likes.innerHTML = "<%= j render partial: 'posts/likescount' %>";
```

В контроллере *likes_controller.rb* в конец экшена *create*:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render 'posts/show.js.erb' }
end
```

Таким образом, при создании лайка, экшен *create* рендерит *show.js.erb*, который  отдельно рендерит @post.likes.count во вьюху *show.html.haml*.